# Is it possible to outsource lifecycle hooks in VueJS

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Can lifecycle hooks (such as created / mounted) be placed in a separate file for simplicity/tidiness.
*MyGreatView.vue*

```
import created from 'created.js'
export default {
  created,
  // created() { console.log('vue Created') }
  mounted() {
    console.log('vue mounted')
  }
}
```

*created.js*

```
created () {
  console.log('vue created')
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Definitely.

but there is some wrong systax in your code sample

in component, if `created.js` is in the same directory as the component file

```
import created from "./created.js";
export default {
  created
};
```

in created.js, export a function which is going to be used as `created`

```
export default function() {
  console.log("vue mounted");
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Jacob :-)